# Using libcurl to upload files to DropBox

Tags: c++, c, curl, dropbox

I'm trying to use the libcurl in a C/C++ application to post files to DropBox.

I would like to use the "/files (POST)" API as documented here...

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-POST

I am having problems with properly authenticating (OAuth) this call. It is unclear to me how to properly create the authentication signature.

From some a sample I saw, it looked like they were reading in the whole file to create the HMAC-SHA1 encoding on. This seems problematic on large files.

Does anyone have experience or insight using this API or something similar?

Comment: +1 Can't help you, But awesome idea! Are you doing a project? Is it open-source?

Comment: Looking at the Oauth api, you formulate an HTTP request, then generate a "Signature Base String" with that, and then use HMAC-SHA1 on that string to generate the signature. See Appendix A.5.1 on http://oauth.net/core/1.0/

Comment: @Bob Brown Hi have you successfully implemented files-POST with C++? im trying so hard to get this work.. hopefully you can help out.

Answer (score 1):

I have just use the libouth and libcurl to get information from sina weibo.  here is my example for you refer. you can also refer the liboauth test programmer in the tests dir, oauthtest.c

```
    if (use_post)
    {
        req_url = oauth_sign_url2(test_call_uri, &postarg, OA_HMAC, NULL, c_key, c_secret, t_key, t_secret);
        reply = oauth_http_post(req_url,postarg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [BOOST ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) . Makes uploading and downloading a breeze.

Comment: Have you used boost asio for dropbox? Or do you mean uploading/downloading in general?